# Index when using is null in query not working

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS dateIdx ON table1 (DateFirstAdded COLLATE NOCASE)
```

The following `ORDER BY` section of the query successfully uses the index:

```
ORDER BY DateFirstAdded COLLATE NOCASE ASC LIMIT 100
```

But the following does not:

```
ORDER BY DateFirstAdded is null COLLATE NOCASE, DateFirstAdded COLLATE NOCASE ASC LIMIT 100
```

Is it a new index I need to make, or a query adjustment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index cannot be used to speed up sorting *after* the records have been read from the table; the only way to use it is to step through the index entries *while* the query is reading data from the table.

This means that the order of the entries in the index must be exactly the same order that is specified in the ORDER BY clause.

In this case, there is no index that has `DateFirstAdded IS NULL` as its first column (and SQLite doesn't support expression indexes); your index has the NULL records at the end.
(Please note that IS NULL returns either 0 or 1, which does not need a collation.)

To return the NULL records last and still use an index for sorting, you have to split the query into a compound query that returns non-NULL and NULL records separately; to be able to use ORDER BY, you have to use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM table1
      WHERE DateFirstAdded IS NOT NULL         -- uses index
      ORDER BY DateFirstAdded COLLATE NOCASE)  -- implied by index scan
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE DateFirstAdded IS NULL                   -- uses index
LIMIT 100
```